# How do I run PHP file in Ubuntu and fix the permission denied?

Tags: permissions, php

When I try to save the file of PHP in Ubuntu I get that error:

```
unable to save /var/www/html/script.php 
Error permission denied
```

How can I fix this error and save/run the PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

the problem that I faced was in permissions so, I have to change the chmod of a directory which I working on so, in this case, I should write the following command:

```
$ sudo chmod  o+w /var/www/html
```

The o stands for other and the + adds the permissions w is write.

at this moment the mode of the whole directory will change from reading to writing mode

Comment: This is probably fine for local development, but should *not* be used in production - especially if the machine is shared by multiple (untrusted) users.